# Trying to maintain a row number based on user ids

Tags: postgresql, psql

I want to maintain a row number in my table based on "User Ids".

Example:

```
Number | UserId | Datetime | Otherfields...
1      |  1     |    xx    |    ...
2      |  1     |    xx    |    ...
3      |  1     |    xx    |    ...
1      |  2     |    xx    |    ...
2      |  2     |    xx    |    ...
```

I came up with row_number but found that it is slower with large datasets.
I want to query 100+ million records.
What could be most efficient way to do this?

Comment: If you select all 100 million rows, that will be slow. Select only part of the data.

Comment: *I want to query 100+ million records.* What for?

Comment: I don't want to select million records, But am maintaining a pokemon game where users can sort there pokemons according to their pokemon numbers (Based on when they caught that pokemon). It was going well in start but now users crossed 100 thousands+ pokemons. I have to include row number in every row (Because I want pagination too).

Comment: So you want the numbers to be (dynamically) permanent. Add a column for the numbers, calculate them once and create a trigger to update them when needed.

Comment: create an index on useid then apply row_number().

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, Storing numbers and updating them when necessary seems good option to me.